# WordPress integration with Backbone or AngularJS

Tags: customization, backbone

I'm learning AngularJS, but I notice that a lot of people use Backbone when doing themes with WordPress.

Is the decision based on personal preference? or are there parts of the WordPress API made to specifically deal with Backbone?

Comment: The Media Manager was rewritten primarily in Backbone in 3.5, so people tend to default to that when choosing a js framework.

Comment: If you building something on the admin side of things, you might be better off with Backbone. But on the front-end side, you pretty much can use whatever you want.